# How can I search if en element from one List exists in the elements in the other list and then print this element

Tags: java, selenium

I have one List of String Elements reading from a property file and then returning a List of these elements:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getExpextedTestDataForHeaderList() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> testDataList = new ArrayList<String>();

    testDataList.add(hpExpectedTxtStoiximaBtn());
    testDataList.add(hpExpectedTxtLiveStoiximaBtn());
    testDataList.add(hpExpectedTxtVirtualBtn());
    testDataList.add(hpExpectedTxtCasinoBtn());
    testDataList.add(hpExpectedTxtLiveCasinoBtn());
    testDataList.add(hpExpectedTxtOtherGamesBtn());
    testDataList.add(hpExpectedTxtLogInBtn());
    testDataList.add(hpExpectedTxtRegisterBtn());


    for (int i = 0; i < testDataList.size(); i++) {
        String actualTitle = testDataList.get(i).toString();
        //System.out.println("From File: "+actualTitle);
    }
    return testDataList;
}
```

Then I have a method to get the elements (`getElementsNames`) and convert them in to a second list

```
private static ArrayList<String> methodConvertElementToList(String path) {
    ArrayList<String> list = getElementsNames(path);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        return list;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Up to this point when I execute my program I get back 2 list with elements.

Now, how I can search from the second list if contains elements of the first list and then print those elements in screen?

I came up with some code but it is not working. Can anyone help with this?

```
public static void printToScreen(String path,List<String> expectedDataList) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> expectedNames = (ArrayList<String>) expectedDataList;
    ArrayList<String> actualNames = getElementsNames(path);
    //ListIterator<String> expectedNamesListIterator = expectedNames.listIterator();
    //ListIterator<String> actualNamesListIterator = actualNames.listIterator();
}
```

With iterators? Or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understand, you can simply use a **listA.containsAll(listB)** example code looks like

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<>(
            List.of("ala",
                    "adam",
                    "bocian",
                    "hello",
                    "world"));

List<String> listB = new ArrayList<>(
            List.of("ala",
                    "hello"));

if(listA.containsAll(listB)){
    System.out.println("YOUR CODE");
}
```

It returns true if all element of listB are present in listA, then you can simply print all elements of listB.

Other way if you don't wanna check all elements you can get individual element of listA and check if it present in listB

```
listA.stream()
            .filter(listB::contains)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Yes more or less this is the case, the second option does the work, thank you very much